# WPF Binding to Window property failing

Tags: wpf, binding

I've got a custom control class in my project called "CarSystemWindow".  It descends from Window and has a custom template that gives all windows in my application the same look.  It also defines two dependency properties named DeviceName and DeviceType.  These are of type string.  They default to "Vehicle: " and "Car 54", respectively.

In my main program, I retrieve a row from my database into a View Model object and save that in a normal CLR property called Site during the program's initialization.  In the MainWindow's xaml, I have the following code:

```
<cs:CarSystemWindow x:Class="....MainWindow"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:..."
                    xmlns:cs="..."
                    Background="Black" 
                    Closed="Window_Closed" 
                    DataContext="{Binding Path=Site, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                    DeviceName="{Binding Path=SiteName}" 
                    DeviceType="{Binding Path=SiteTypeName}"
                    Icon="..." 
                    Height="600" 
                    Loaded="Window_Loaded" 
                    ResizeMode="CanMinimize" 
                    SourceInitialized="Window_SourceInitialized" 
                    Title="Window Title" 
                    Width="800" 
                    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
```

At run time, the binding on the DataContext attribute is failing with the following message:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Site; DataItem=null; target element is 'MainWindow' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

I'm using this same binding code elsewhere and it works.  I've even turned the Site property into a dependency property and its still failing.

Does anyone give have ideas why the binding is failing?

Thanks

Tony

Comment: Do you mean the "Site" property is defined in this windows code behind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to change your binding to this:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Site}
```

The reason your current binding is not working is that you are trying to go up a level in the hierarchy from the Window, but you actually want the Window.

Here is a good source for figuring out what the binding string should be for different scenarios:

http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf

Comment: Hey! I was typing that :-). Alternatively he could just set the DataContext in the contructor and have the same result.

Comment: @Tony, by the way, here is a good source for all your binding scenarios: http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `DataContext` binding is that the line is saying to use the `Site` property on an object that is an ancestor of this object, and of type `Window`. Since this object is a `Window` already, and therefore at the root of the visual tree, there are no ancestors to search and find the specified property.

Why don't you assign the `DataContext` where this object is constructed?

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I could have assigned the object to teh DataContext in code, but I wanted to do it in Xaml.